# Changing joomla site address

Tags: joomla

I've copied an existing joomla site from one domain to another, but when I hit the menu items it redirects to the old domain articles.  Where is the setting to change this?

Thanks

Comment: Easiest way around (if the menu is not long) is to create links again.

Answer (score 3):

Set `$live_site` variable in your `configuration.php` file by adding this line:

```
$live_site = "http://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 3):

Narkoz's answer isn't correct, there isn't an option to set your site domain in the joomla backend.
The problem isn't that joomla doesn't know your site URL, it gets that from you server, but rather the menu links are probably hard coded. Check your menu links in the backend and make sure the point to an "internal" link of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Export the database to SQL file then open it with a text editor and do a search/replace

Search : old-site-url.com

and replace it by : new-site-url.com

Save your file and import it to the database.

Comment: How would he export all schema tables data inside a single file ?

Comment: I've read some instructions found on Google, some of them was quite detailed but none of them mentioned that crucial step.
Thanks.